# Inline display property dont works to a form element

Tags: html, css

i am very new at CSS and i am trying to create a login form. The problem is that i use the inline display property in order to put the input elements the one next to the other (as a row), but with the bellow code it does not work as i expect. Can someone explain me why?

```css
#container {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form id="container">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [localize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the form to `display: inline` will cause it to not trigger a line break before and after *the entire form*. It will have little effect on the *contents* of the form.

The input and label elements are `display: inline` by default. They appear on separate lines because you have explicit line breaks (`<br>`) between them. If you don't want those line breaks: delete them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as i can understand due to at this case we do not have block elements, it does not work. If we had for example list elements which are block elements (as a result the keep an entire line), the inline command would work. Am i right?

Comment: (a) You don't have  block elements, you have one form, which is one element, singular. (b) Line breaks between inputs and labels are line breaks. Changing the `display` of the `form` to `inline` isn't going to change what `br` means.